# toString Override in Java

Tags: java, performance, tostring

This question is from an assignment. I have to override a toString() method in a class that creates a circularly linked list and I actually have a toString() method that works great, it passes all of my tests everything. So my project is autograded and it apparently doesn't approve of my method 100%. So my question is: is there a better way to write this toString() method that would be more efficient?

```
public String toString()
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            return "[]";
        }
        else
        {
            String output = "";
            Node<E> tempNode = actualElement;
            while (tempNode.next() != actualElement)
            {
                if (output.equals(""))
                {
                    output = "[" + output + tempNode.data().toString();
                    tempNode = tempNode.next();
                }
                else
                {
                    output = output + ", " + tempNode.data().toString();
                    tempNode = tempNode.next();
                }

            }
            output = output + ", " + tempNode.data().toString() + "]";
            return output;
        }
```

If i need to elaborate more on the class structure so that this makes more sense let me know.

Comment: You should use a `StringBuilder` for efficient concatenation.

Comment: You say it's autograded. Do you know the exact grading criterias?

Comment: String concatenation with `+` in a loop is sub-optimal, which is probably why you got dinged on the auto-grade. Use a `StringBuilder` as others have suggested.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I don't know what the grading criteria is....I have tried a couple differnt ways to build the string but this is my "best" so far.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips it seems like everyone is pointing me toward StringBuilder so I will look into that and see what result I get.

Comment: FYI, the compiler may optimize "+" to use StringBuilder: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("some text");
builder.append("more text");
return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve it further, you can use StringBuilder and append each computed String literals. This saves JVM creating load of individual String literals and thus improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use a StringBuilder for concatenation of your Strings.

take a look here:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2011/07/string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder.html

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuidler();
Node<E> tempNode = actualElement;

while (tempNode.next() != actualElement)
{
    if (sb.length() == 0)
    {
        sb.append("[").append(tempNode.data().toString());
    }
    else
    {
        sb.append(", ").append(tempNode.data().toString());
    }
    tempNode = tempNode.next();
}
sb.append(", ").append(tempNode.data().toString()).append("]");
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Strings` should always be used unless [string builders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) offer an advantage in terms of simpler code  or better **performance**

if you need to concatenate a large number of strings, appending to a `StringBuilder` `object` is more **efficient**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` instead may do your a favor.This is snippet is copied from `AbstractCollection.toString()`,take a look at it.

```
 public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
if (! i.hasNext())
    return "[]";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('[');
for (;;) {
    E e = i.next();
    sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
    if (! i.hasNext())
    return sb.append(']').toString();
    sb.append(", ");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `actualElement` is defined elsewhere in the class, though a better name might be nice. The `if (output.equals(""))` is unnecessary.  Just start the output `StringBuilder` with a [, and just append to it.

However, you are depending on your list actually being circular.  If this list ends up not looping around, you will get an NPE.  And, if the list looks more like a 6, as in [A, B, C, D, E, C, D, E...], then the loop will never end.